# Firebase persisted write failing after being offline

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an Android application that uses Firebase as backend. Now that Firebase has  support for local persistence I decided to get rid of my own local storage solution and use the built-in instead.

Everything is working, except for one thing. Making changes while being offline, closing the app, connect, and start the app.

The code that I use to update my data on the server is something like this:

```
public void saveDataToServer(String id, Boolean isHandled) {
    Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/item_data/items/1234/data").child(id);
    if(firebase == null)
        return;

    firebase.authWithCustomToken(mToken, mAuthResultHandler);

    Map<String, Object> children = new HashMap<>();
    children.put("updated_at", FireBaseHelper.getFormattedTimestamp());
    children.put("is_handled", isHandled);
    firebase.updateChildren(children);
}
```

mMainFirebaseInstance is some Firebase object that is on the root level of where this data is saved. And this all runs in a `Service` that is connected to my Activities/Fragments

*Sidenote:
I get the authentication token `mToken` from some REST API that someone else made for me to use.*

**When I am connected, have the app connected and make changes: everything works**

**When I am not connected, open the app, make changes, close the app, open the app and connect: everything works**

**When I am not connected, open the app, make changes, close the app, connect and open the app:
The following error is logged:**

`06-22 17:51:52.343  28073-28395/? W/RepoOperation﹕ Persisted write at /item_data/items/7454/data/7454141033945571998119 failed: FirebaseError: Invalid token in path`

I've searched in Firebase's documentation and can't figure out where the problem is. I would say that this has something to do with the authentication, but I don't know anymore where to look.

So my question is: What is the problem here? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The FireBaseHelper looks like this:

```
class FireBaseHelper {
    public static Firebase getItemsBase(String itemId) {
        Firebase fb = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL + "item_data/items/" + itemId + "/data");
        return fb;
    }

    public static String getFormattedTimestamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        return simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
}
```

It can create the main Firebase instance and return a timestamp in a specific format. Constants.FIREBASE_URL is just `https://example.firebaseio.com/`

EDIT2:

```
mMainFirebaseInstance = FireBaseHelper.getItemsBase("1234");
```

which would be replaceable by

```
mMainFirebaseInstance = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/item_data/items/1234/data");
```

A possible timestamp is:

```
2015-06-22 23:12:24
```

The id that is used in the saveDataToServer is retrieved from a snapshot that is given to me in a ValueEventListener. For example:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap data = dataSnapshot.getValue(HashMap.class);
            Set keySet = data.keySet();
            String id = keySet.get(0);
        }
        ...
}
```

EDIT3:

Android: 5.0
Firebase: 2.3.0+
Java: 7

Comment: To allow us to replay your scenario, can you provide a path for `mMainFirebaseInstance` and a value for `FireBaseHelper.getFormattedTimestamp()`? Also: is auth necessary to get the proble? Or does the problem also appear if you don't require authentication?

Comment: The auth is necessary for me to do anything at all. Changes added.

Comment: @se_bastiaan Your app's security policy may require auth, but reproducing the bug may not. Part of due diligence for troubleshooting would be to distill this to the [minimum required code to reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thus, a first step would be to remove the security restrictions, remove the auth, and try this without to see if auth is a necessary step in reproducing.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like the auth token may be invalid, so perhaps it's expiring. What is your session length and how is authentication being invoked? These little code samples aren't enough to help you debug.

Comment: @Kato Did you read the sidenote? I did not build the API that gives me the authentication token so you're asking questions I can't answer. I'll contact the Firebase admin and will ask if he can remove the authentication measures. But I don't think that will help, the error message for an invalid authentication token would be different (according to the API reference) and according to those same docs: Firebase should wait for a valid token before trying to update the data.

Comment: @se_bastiaan we're trying to reduce the problem to its minimum, so that we can reproduce it. E.g. it is highly likely that you'll get the same problem with a hard-coded value for `updated_at", meaning we don't need `FireBaseHelper`. Similarly: if the problem also appears without auth, we don't need to worry about how auth might be impacting the code. Reducing a problem like that, reduces the surface area we all have to consider to find the cause.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize `mMainFirebaseInstance` and the `id` that you pass to `saveDataToServer`?

Comment: I just ran the following snippet in a JVM and it wrote the values without problems: `Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/30987733"); /*ref.authWithCustomToken(mToken, mAuthResultHandler);*/ Map<String, Object> children = new HashMap<String, Object>(); children.put("updated_at", "2015-06-22 23:12:24"); children.put("is_handled", true); ref.updateChildren(children);`. Can you try if this works in your environment?

Comment: Same problem. `06-23 11:54:00.615    8445-8739/? W/RepoOperation﹕ Persisted write at /30987733 failed: FirebaseError: Invalid token in path` I have made the specific conditions in which the error occurs bold in my text.

Comment: So, it turns out that this reducing the problem set has some merit after all, and everyone isn't just trying to annoy you. Yay! A bit more tinkering here will probably uncover the exact conditions needed to create the issue. Firstly, given that it's working for Puf and not you, it seems like knowing as much detail as possible about the environment where the code is compiled and run will be necessary (at least the Java, Firebase, and Android versions).

Comment: Haha. I'm cooled down now, got a bit overheated trying to fix this. Maybe I can write a small Android application in which the problem occurs and then put it on GitHub so that you can try to reproduce this? I will put the exact versions in the post.

Comment: That sounds perfect @se_bastiaan! It might also be useful to trim the question down a bit as it's now a bit much. E.g. I tested in a JVM, which of course doesn't allow me to connect/disconnect (at least not easily). I haven't gotten around to testing in Android yet.

Comment: Good catch! It turned out to be a bug in the Firebase Android SDK. It has been fixed in version 2.3.1 that was just released. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/changelog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This turned out to be a bug in the Firebase Android SDK. It has been fixed in version 2.3.1 that was just released.** See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/changelog.html

I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing with this `Activity.onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/30987733");
    Map<String, Object> children = new HashMap<>();
    children.put("updated_at", new Date().toString());
    children.put("is_handled", true);
    ref.updateChildren(children);
}
```

The steps to reproduce that go with the above code:

1. Go into airplane mode
2. Start the app (so that it calls `updateChildren`
3. Kill the app
4. Go online
5. Start the app

In my tests, the second update *does* get written to Firebase. But there is a warning written in the Android logs:

```
W/RepoOperation﹕ Persisted write at /30987733 failed: FirebaseError: Invalid token in path
```

Comment: I guess my GitHub example is not needed anymore then. It wouldn't have more than this.